# Build failed react-native 0.73 mmkv-storage contains no files

Tags: react-native

When I run npx react-native run-android It throws the next error:

A problem occurred evaluating project ':[react-native-mmkv-storage](https://github.com/ammarahm-ed/react-native-mmkv-storage)'.

> Expected directory '...\node_modules\react-native-mmkv-storage\android' to contain exactly one file, however, it contains no files.

The error is on line 138 of the build.gradle file:

```
  def rnAAR = fileTree("$reactNative").matching({ it.include rnAarMatcher }).singleFile
```

I have upgraded all modules with `yarn upgrade` and I'm using the latest react-native version. I have tried to create a fresh new project, add all my sources, and then run `yarn install` to install all required modules, but with the same result.